# Field cannot be set as primary key since there are duplicated values for fieldin Class

Tags: java, android, realm

I cant understand, why i get this message. I create realm DB, where I have table with primaryKey. In my Migration I set field as primaryKey. But when my users update or REINSTALL the app brokes down.

I dont understand what does this error mean. When I launch app in my phone it work successfull.

in MyMigration

```
public class TasksMigration implements RealmMigration {
@Override
public void migrate(DynamicRealm realm, long oldVersion, long newVersion) {
    final RealmSchema schema = realm.getSchema();
    if (oldVersion == 0) {
        oldVersion++;
    }
    if (oldVersion == 1) {
     if (!schema.contains("GoodsModelDB")) {
            schema.create("GoodsModelDB")
                    .addField("idGoodsPK", String.class, FieldAttribute.PRIMARY_KEY, FieldAttribute.REQUIRED)
                    .addField("id", long.class)
                    .addField("name", String.class)
                    .addField("note", String.class)
                    .addField("code", String.class)
                    .addField("model", String.class)
                    .addField("category", String.class)
                    .addField("type", String.class)
                    .addField("count", int.class);
        }

     final RealmObjectSchema goodsModelDB = schema.get("GoodsModelDB");
        if (goodsModelDB != null) {
            if (!goodsModelDB.getFieldNames().contains("idGoodsPK"))
                goodsModelDB.addField("idGoodsPK", String.class, FieldAttribute.PRIMARY_KEY, FieldAttribute.REQUIRED);
            if (!goodsModelDB.getFieldNames().contains("id"))
                goodsModelDB.addField("id", long.class);
            if (!goodsModelDB.getFieldNames().contains("name"))
                goodsModelDB.addField("name", String.class);
            if (!goodsModelDB.getFieldNames().contains("note"))
                goodsModelDB.addField("note", String.class);
            if (!goodsModelDB.getFieldNames().contains("code"))
                goodsModelDB.addField("code", String.class);
            if (!goodsModelDB.getFieldNames().contains("model"))
                goodsModelDB.addField("model", String.class);
            if (!goodsModelDB.getFieldNames().contains("category"))
                goodsModelDB.addField("category", String.class);
            if (!goodsModelDB.getFieldNames().contains("type"))
                goodsModelDB.addField("type", String.class);
            if (!goodsModelDB.getFieldNames().contains("count"))
                goodsModelDB.addField("count", int.class);

        }
    oldVersion++;
    }
```

in my RealmObject

```
public class GoodsModelDB extends RealmObject implements Serializable {
@PrimaryKey
@Required
String idGoodsPK;
private long id;
private String name;
private String note;
private String code;
private String model;
private String category;
private String type;
private double price;
private boolean isActivated;
private long idSalePoint;
private long agentId;
private Date dateActivated;
private Date bindDate;
private double arpu;
private String pkOfSalePoint;
private boolean consign;
private long visitId;
private String idVisitByPK;
private boolean withoutException;
private boolean hasChanged;


public GoodsModelDB() {
}}
```

after update my app in PlayMarket i recive this error in fabric

```
    Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ru.mitapp.dist_android/ru.mitapp.dist_android.screen.preloade.PreloadeActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field 'idGoodsPK' cannot be set as primary key since there are duplicated values for field 'idGoodsPK' in Class 'GoodsModelDB'.
   (/Users/Nabil/Dev/realm/master/realm-java/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_OsObjectStore.cpp:74)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2423)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2483)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
```

Comment: Evidently, it is because you are adding a new field, you already have more than 1 row in the database, and the default field value should be `null` and therefore you are trying to set PK when every row has `null` as PK value, clearly that won't be unique will it?

Comment: Instead of `.getFieldNames().contains("idGoodsPK")`, you could just use `.hasField("isGoodsPK")`.

Comment: But when user delete app, will database contain rows? If yes, what should I do?

Comment: `oldVersion == 0` won't create the  table anew. If you already had data in there, you need to create the field and set values that make PK unique.

Comment: How should i do this? if I delete app, it mean that all data in DB will delete. In this case how can DB contain data?

Comment: Auto-backup, most likely.